# Guardar la puntuación más alta

Tags: javascript, phaser

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto personal que consiste en una ruleta. El otro día ya comenté el proyecto para otra pregunta que fue resuelta de forma satisfactoria.

Para jugar a esta ruleta, no hay que registrarse ni colocar tu nombre ni nada (aunque sería algo interesante). Lo que hace es sumar los puntos que te van tocando pero si caes en "Perder" lo pierdes todo. La cuestión es ¿cómo almacenar el puntaje más alto? Si hago 1500 puntos y la siguiente tirada lo pierdo, me gustaría que mostrara en la pantalla que la mayor puntuación fue 1500 puntos, para poder compartirlo en Twitter, por ejemplo (que eso será luego :)

He creado dos variables:

```
var highscore = 0; //inicializo la máxima puntuación a 0
var highScoreText; //texto que mostrará la máxima puntuación
```

Les he dado estilo:

```
// Máxima puntuación
 highScoreText = this.game.add.text(600, 40, 'HS: ' + highscore, {
        font: '25px Arial',
        fill: 'black'
    });

this.puntos = 0;
    this.labelPuntos = game.add.text(20, 20, "0", 
    { font: "30px Arial", fill: "black" });
```

Y le he colocado la función siguiente:

```
winPrize(){
          canSpin = true;
          prizeText.text = slicePrizes[prize].title;
          // Sumamos y mostramos la acumulación de puntos, si cae en 0 pierde todo y se resetean los puntos a 0
                if (slicePrizes[prize].value === 'reset'){
                    puntos = 0;
                } else {
                    puntos += slicePrizes[prize].value;
                }
            puntosText.text = puntos;

// Actualización de máxima puntuación
highScoreText.text = 'HS: ' + localStorage.getItem("highscore");
  {
     if (this.puntos > localStorage.getItem("highscore")) 
        { 
            localStorage.setItem("highscore", this.puntos);
        }
    }

this.puntos += 1;
this.labelPuntos.text = this.puntos;  

     }
```

El problema es que me cuenta las veces que hago clic en la ruleta, no los puntos que llevo acumulados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar con este código:

```
if (slicePrizes[prize].value === 'reset'){
    if (puntos > highscore) {
        highscore = puntos;
    }
    puntos = 0;
}
```

Lo que hacemos es que, al momento de que nos toque "reset", vemos si el puntaje que tenemos es mayor al que teníamos como "highscore" y si es así, nuestro puntaje actual sería igual al highscore. Así "guardamos" el puntaje más grande dentro de highscore. Luego podemos reiniciar los puntos.

### Usando localStorage

Ahora si lo que quieres es guardar la puntuación aunque el usuario se vaya del sitio, tenemos que hacer lo siguiente:

Primero, obtenemos, si lo hay, el valor desde localStorage:

```
// Devuelve lo que hay en "highscore" pero si no hay nada, entonces devuelve 0.
var highscore = localStorage.getItem('highscore') || 0;
// Como localStorage devuelve un string, lo convertimos en número:
highscore = +highscore;
```

Luego ocupamos nuestra función:

```
if (slicePrizes[prize].value === 'reset'){
    if (puntos > highscore) {
        highscore = puntos;
        localStorage.setItem('highscore', highscore);
    }
    puntos = 0;
}
```

Así queda guardado nuestro puntaje aunque salgamos del sitio.

Comment: No me funciona. Lo he colocado dentro del `if` que ya tenía creado. Pero creo que debe utilizarse `localStorage` pero no me funciona como yo quiero.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es guardar aunque el usuario "salga" del sitio, si, usa localStorage. Voy a actualizar la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero. Me faltaba convertir el String a número y mostrarlo correctamente. Por cierto la wheel funciona si hago clic en cualquier parte del canvas ¿hay manera de que funcione solo haciendo clic en el Spin, en el centro?

Comment: Mira, de javascript se mucho, pero de phaser no se nada :/ te recomiendo buscar o, si no encuentras nada, hacer otra pregunta